# AngularJS - how to highlight/add class to a max value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let say I have a very simple data that Im looping through with `ng-repeat`.

Now, how can I highlight (add a css class) to a highest value in the data.

Data:

```
$scope.marks = [
        {point:'11'},
        {point:'2'},
        {point:'23'}
];
```

html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="value in marks" class={{here add class for value 23}}> //how to add class to li with max value, in this case it is 23
    {{ value.point}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Many thanks for your help

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/VcjXJbPgIRLn4kVjzHbi?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use calculate the max value in a watch:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('marks', function(items) {
  $scope.maxPoint = -1; // assuming we won't have negative values
  angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
    if (parseInt(item.point) > $scope.maxPoint) {
      $scope.maxPoint = item.point;
    }
  });
});
```

Then use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive in your markup:

```
<li ng-repeat="value in marks" ng-class="{max : value.point == maxPoint}">
    {{ value.point}}
</li>
```

Like Petr pointed out this won't perform well. Calculating the max value on changes is a better way. Here's a working plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/F8yjoWR0ZWVF4tcck1rH?p=preview

Comment: quadratic time makes me sad

Comment: @PetrAveryanov refactored it now :)

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but it's not working fro me :( [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/VcjXJbPgIRLn4kVjzHbi?p=preview)

Comment: @angular_learner Just paste the watch function in your own controller and change the markup like above.

Comment: what if the data coming in dynamically using `$http` and `get` function?